# Networking in swift outside a playground or project?

Tags: swift, bash, networking

I was trying to build a program that I would regularly run to check if a website has changed. It's working in Swift Playgrounds, however, if I try to just copy it over to a .swift file and to then run it directly in the terminal, it doesn't return a response. In fact, it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Here's my code:

```
func getSite(website: String) {
    let url = URL(string: website)!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            if let data = data, let host = response?.url?.host, let scheme = response?.url?.scheme {
                print("Retrieved data from \(host) over \(scheme)...")
                let site = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                print(site)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Your main thread is terminating your process before the async thread's has a chance to run the completion handler. You would need to wait on something like a semaphore or dispatch group, that's unlocked only after the completion handler is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just figured it out - Alexander's comment was a huge help.

I just needed to set up a semaphore:

```
var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
```

and `semaphore.wait()` right after running the async thread. At the end of the completion handler, I put `semaphore.signal()`. That's it!